# PostgreSQL - Auto Cast for types?

Tags: postgresql

I'm working on porting database from Firebird to PostgreSQL and have many errors related to type cast. For example let's take one simple function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_Concat3 (
  s1 varchar, s2 varchar, s3 varchar
)
RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
BEGIN
   return s1||s2||s3;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE CALLED ON NULL INPUT SECURITY INVOKER LEAKPROOF COST 100;
```

As Firebird is quite flexible to types this functions was called differently: some of the arguments might be another type: integer/double precision/timestamp. And of course in Postgres function call `f_Concat3 ('1', 2, 345.345)` causes an error like:

> function f_Concat3(unknown, integer, numeric) not found.

The documentation is recomended to use an explicit cast like:

```
f_Concat3 ('1'::varchar, 2::varchar, 345.345::varchar)
```

Also I can create a function clones for all possible combinations of types what might occur and it will work. An example to resolve error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_Concat3 (
   s1 varchar, s2 integer, s3 numeric
)
RETURNS varchar AS
$body$
  BEGIN
    return s1::varchar||s2::varchar||s3::varchar;
  END;
```

However this is very bad and ugly and it wont work with big functions.

**Important:** We have one general code base for all DB and use our own language to create application objects (forms, reports, etc) which contains select queries. It is not possible to use explicit cast on function calls cause we will lose compatibility with other DB.

I am confused that the integer argument can not be casted to the `numeric` or `double precision`, or `date` / `number` to a `string`. I even face problems with `integer` to `smallint`, and vice versa. Most database act not like this.

Is there any best practice for such situation?
Is there any alternatives for explicit cast?

Comment: You can just use `::varchar` when you call the function.

Comment: Why do you want to create a new function? Postgres already has a `concat()` function that takes any number of arguments?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name the concat() function is for example. Just imagine any complex function where any input arguments can be written as integer or string. Firebird will allow that.

Comment: I would say that running identical SQL on different systems is just not possible; and generating SQL from a template for your target database includes understanding its type system. Also, an explicit cast could be cross-platform, if you use the standard `CAST(value AS type)` syntax.

Comment: @IMSoP It works cause of sql standards, i just can't explain it properly. Of course all tables, constraints, functions, triggers are converted. But business logic (our language) use quite simple select statements (which sometimes a bit changes by our compilator depends on DB configuration). It's complicated. Also codebase is very big, some clients have they own reports with sql-logic which we can't change

Comment: @Ice2burn Sure, there's a standard, and there's even some parts of the standard that are pretty closely followed by most of the vendors. But that pretty quickly evaporates, and you start needing to re-generate your SQL. And, as I say, cast syntax is a well-followed part of that standard, so I don't see the problem.

Comment: @IMSoP system is based on firebird syntax (since 2002) which is then converted. We have overcome problems with deviations from the standard in MS and Oracle. Now we face PostgreSQL and it seems this war is lost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SQL is a typed language, and PostgreSQL takes that more seriously than other relational databases. Unfortunately that means extra effort when porting an application with sloppy coding.

It is tempting to [add implicit casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html), but [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-overview.html) warns you from creating casts between built-in data types:

> Additional casts can be added by the user with the [CREATE CAST](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createcast.html) command. (This is usually done in conjunction with defining new data types. The set of casts between built-in types has been carefully crafted and is best not altered.)

This is not an idle warning, because [function resolution](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/typeconv-func.html) and other things may suddenly fail or misbehave if you create new casts between existing types.

I think that if you *really* don't want to clean up the code (which would make it more portable for the future), you have no choice but to add more versions of your functions.

Fortunately PostgreSQL has [function overloading](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/xfunc-overload.html) which makes that possible.

You can make the job easier by using one argument with a [polymorphic type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/extend-type-system.html#EXTEND-TYPES-POLYMORPHIC) in your function definition, like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_concat3 (
   s1 text, s2 integer, s3 anyelement
) RETURNS text
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE LEAKPROOF AS
'SELECT f_concat3(s1, s2::text, s3::text)';
```

You cannot use more than one `anyelement` argument though, because that will only work if all such parameters are of the same type.

If you use function overloading, be careful that you don't create ambiguities that would make function resolution fail.

Comment: It would really be nice if Postgres would allow to create a function like `concat()` (which is defined with a single parameter of type `"any"`) using SQL or PL/pgSQL but that only seems possible with C

Comment: There are some legacy functions with more then 13 arguments, so function overloading is the last option. Pseudo-Type was my last hope :)